# datenum series to the end of February - Leap year or not

Tags: matlab, date, time-series

I want to create a list of dates that go until the end of February. However, since the end of February changes from 28 to 29 depending on whether there's a leap year, I'm having trouble with how to consider both options.

Here's what I have so far:

```
date = datenum(years(i),12,01):1:datenum(years(i)+1,02,29);
```

This case, when run on a year that is not a leap year, ends up counting March 1st instead of ending on Feb. 28th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a little hack I came up with. You can check whether a year is a leap year quite easily by calculating the number of days between February 28 and March 1, like so:

```
datenum(years(i), 3, 1) - datenum(years(i), 2, 28)
```

Checking whether it's larger than 1 would indicate leap year. This 1 or 0 `logical` MATLAB convention leads to the second part of the hack: this is exactly the number of days you need to add to Feb 28: 0 if not leap year, 1 if leap year. Here, therefore, is the full hack:

```
date = datenum(years(i),12,01):datenum(years(i)+1,02, ...
               28 + ((datenum(years(i)+1,3,1) - datenum(years(i)+1,2,28))>1) );
```

**UPDATE / IMPROVEMENT:**
Answer already accepted, but I came up with an even better solution. I didn't realize that `datenum` simply counts days. In this case, we can simply say that the last day of February is *the day before March 1*. This yields the following drastic simplification:

```
date = datenum(years(i),12,01):1:(datenum(years(i)+1,3,1)-1);
```

Comment: Datenum, for good or ill, also takes negative and zero numbers.  So the last day of February can be written: `datenum(2015, 3, 0)`.  With a comment explaining this madness, of course.

Comment: @Peter You should definitely post that as an answer!

Comment: OK, but just for future reference.  I honestly think `datenum(2015, 3, 1) - 1` is better for expressing the intention.

Answer (score 2):

Datenum, for good or ill, takes negative and zero numbers. So the last day of February can be written:

```
datenum(2015, 3, 0)
```

With a comment explaining this madness, of course.